# Allowing escape sequences in my regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression which finds occurences of $VAR or ${VAR}. If something like \$VAR or \${VAR} was given, it would not match. If it were given something like \\$VAR or \\${VAR} or any multiple of 2 \'s, it should match.

```
i.e.
$BLOB matches
\$BLOB doesn't match
\\$BLOB matches
\\\$BLOB doesn't match
\\\\$BLOB matches
... etc
```

I'm currently using the following regex:

```
    line = re.sub("[^\\][\\\\]*\$(\w[^-]+)|"
                  "[^\\][\\\\]*\$\{(\w[^-]+)\}",replace,line)
```

However, this doesn't work properly. When I give it \$BLOB, it still matches for some reason. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

The second groupings of double slashes are written as a redundant character class `[\\\\]*`, matching one or more backslashes, but should be a repeating group `((?:\\\\)*)` matching one or more *sets of two* backslashes:

```
 re.sub(r'(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)\$(\w[^-]+|\{(\w[^-]+)\})',r'\1' + replace, line)
```

Comment: what does the r'\1' do?

Comment: @Apollo The `r'\1'` is the first group. In this case, it puts however many *pairs* of backslashes came first before the replacement, so that they aren't lost. That is, if `line` is `\\$BLOB` and `replace` is `x`, then `line` will become `\\x` instead of just `x`.

Answer (score 0):

To write a regular expression that finds `$` unless it is escaped using `E` unless it in turn is also escaped EE:

```
import re

values = dict(BLOB='some value')
def repl(m):
    return m.group('before') + values[m.group('name').strip('{}')]

regex = r"(?<!E)(?P<before>(?:EE)*)\$(?P<name>N|\{N\})"
regex = regex.replace('E', re.escape('\\'))
regex = regex.replace('N', r'\w+') # name
line = re.sub(regex, repl, line)
```

Using `E` instead of `'\\\\'` exposes your embed language without thinking about backslashes in Python string literals and regular expression patterns.